# SonarQube 6.7 failed to start because CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I've just upgraded SonarQube from 6.0 to 6.7 LTS running in a CentOS 6 box, and noticed that ElasticSearch (ES) failed to start because the kernel (2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64) doesn't have [seccomp](https://lwn.net/Articles/656307/) available.

This is officially documented at [System call filter check](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/_system_call_filter_check.html) and a correct workaround for systems without this feature is to configure `bootstrap.system_call_filter` to false in `elasticsearch.yml`.

The issue here is because Sonar creates the ES configuration at startup, writing in `$SONAR_HOME/temp/conf/es/elasticsearch.yml` and I haven't found a way to set `bootstrap.system_call_filter` property.

I tried a natural (undocumented) way introducing `sonar.search.bootstrap.system_call_filter` and `bootstrap.system_call_filter` properties in `sonar.properties` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried to configure elastic via environment variable substitution setting ES_BOOTSTRAP_SYSTEM_CALL_FILTER=false in sonar.sh. It Doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

We had the same problem. At first we used the above solution but after searching in the sonar code on github found the place where this setting should be placed:

Edit the sonar.properties file and change the line:

`#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=`

to

`sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false`

Comment: It's the correct way to start SonarQube where seccomp has not been compiled into kernel.

Comment: If it helps, it's on inside folder <sonarqube-6.7>/conf folder and on line 215.

Answer (score 2):

For sonarqube docker image, setup additional environment to disable this feature when "docker run":

```
-e SONAR_SEARCH_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS="-Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could really cheat and edit `/${SONAR_HOME}/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`.

Add

```
echo "bootstrap.system_call_filter = 'false'" >> 
/${SONAR_HOME}/temp/conf/es/elasticsearch.yml
```

before the "demonized" variable is set.

Comment: Agree, but this confirms that there's no official and elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to echo bootstrap.system_call_filter: 'false' to temp/conf/es/elasticsearch.yml, I see the line in that file, but got same error during start of sonarqube 6.7 on centos6.

Has someone tested that with success?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: don't even try to update `elasticsearch.yml` . SonarQube self-manages its ElasticSearch component config, so any attempt of manual intervention will be harmful. (reminder: the only config file that should ever be modified to operate SonarQube is `sonar.properties`)

More interestingly regarding that `seccomp` component:

- the `seccomp` requirement does come from [underlying ElasticSearch requirement](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking-changes-5.2.html#_system_call_bootstrap_check), and transitively applies to operating SonarQube
- if you run SonarQube locally with default config (specifically: default *sonar.search.host*), then the `seccomp` check may not be fatal (i.e. just a warning)
- if you did override *sonar.search.host* , then the first thing you should wonder is: does the ElasticSearch JVM really needs to listen on other interfaces than loopback ? (knowing that SonarQube uses ES locally, except with the *Data Center Edition*). If no good answer to that, then keep *sonar.search.host* at its default value.

Last but not least, the golden path here is obviously to follow the requirement (i.e. have `seccomp` available on your OS), even if that involves upgrading to a more recent Linux kernel. And to wrap it all up: we've edited [SonarQube Requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements#Requirements-seccompfilter) to transparently share this situation.