# SonarQube 6.7.1 ES issue with SECCOMP not resolved with recommended solution

Tags: sonarqube, elasticsearch-5

I upgraded an installation of SonarQube from 5.6.6 to 6.7.1, hosted on RHEL without CONFIG_SECCOMP compiled in.  After updating the DB, running the `sonar.sh start` command starts briefly, and then terminates.

Per [SonarQube 6.7 failed to start because CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210302/sonarqube-6-7-failed-to-start-because-config-seccomp-not-compiled-into-kernel) and https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements#Requirements-seccompfilter , my settings in **sonar.properties** are the recommended value for dealing with the CONFIG_SECCOMP issue is set as:

```
sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false
```

For sonar.search.javaOpts, sonar.search.port and sonar.search.host, values are all default.

Per logs (below) it appears that the bootstrap value is being pulled in, but it doesn't seem to be getting propagated into the generated elasticsearch.yml in the temp directory.

---

sonar.log consists of:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.01.08 22:44:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp
2018.01.08 22:44:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.01.08 22:44:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp/conf/es
2018.01.08 22:44:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.01.08 22:44:43 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.01.08 22:44:43 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.01.08 22:44:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2018.01.08 22:44:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1]: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp -server -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:InlineSmallCode=3072 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.1.4.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp/sq-process6699142698739435554properties
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2018.01.08 22:45:00 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

ES log consists of:

```
2018.01.08 22:44:45 WARN  es[][o.e.b.JNANatives] unable to install syscall filter:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: seccomp unavailable: CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel, CONFIG_SECCOMP and CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER are needed
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.SystemCallFilter.linuxImpl(SystemCallFilter.java:364) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.SystemCallFilter.init(SystemCallFilter.java:639) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JNANatives.tryInstallSystemCallFilter(JNANatives.java:258) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.tryInstallSystemCallFilter(Natives.java:113) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:111) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
2018.01.08 22:44:45 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initializing ...
2018.01.08 22:44:45 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt (/dev/mapper/vg_sys-lv_opt)]], net usable_space [2.3gb], net total_space [9.7gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
2018.01.08 22:44:45 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [495.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2018.01.08 22:44:45 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [S0XGTf7ATGC2HuVlIcIwYQ]
2018.01.08 22:44:45 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[5.6.3], pid[3915], build[1a2f265/2017-10-06T20:33:39.012Z], OS[Linux/2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_131/25.131-b11]
2018.01.08 22:44:45 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false, -Des.path.home=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch]
2018.01.08 22:44:46 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
2018.01.08 22:44:46 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [ingest-common]
2018.01.08 22:44:46 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2018.01.08 22:44:46 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2018.01.08 22:44:46 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2018.01.08 22:44:46 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2018.01.08 22:44:46 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2018.01.08 22:44:47 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen]
2018.01.08 22:44:48 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2018.01.08 22:44:48 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2018.01.08 22:44:48 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2018.01.08 22:44:48 WARN  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
2018.01.08 22:44:51 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.ClusterService] new_master {sonarqube}{S0XGTf7ATGC2HuVlIcIwYQ}{CSVhU1O1QF6rU3a9IolATA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonarqube}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
2018.01.08 22:44:51 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] started
2018.01.08 22:44:51 INFO  es[][o.e.g.GatewayService] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
```

Answer (score 3):

> Per logs (below) it appears that the bootstrap value is being pulled in, but it doesn't seem to be getting propagated into the generated elasticsearch.yml in the temp directory.

It's expected that `elasticsearch.yml` is not updated. The .yml is a static internal configuration file. When you pass `-Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false` it is set at runtime, and not reflected in static config files.

As a matter of fact you'll notice that your `es.log` only contains warnings, and is not failing at all on the `seccomp` aspect. Per `sonar.log`, ElasticSearch JVM even successfully starts:

```
2018.01.08 22:44:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
```

So the problem is elsewhere, and your `sonar.log` tells you it's with the Web Process:

```
2018.01.08 22:44:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1]: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp -server -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:InlineSmallCode=3072 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.1.4.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp/sq-process6699142698739435554properties
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
2018.01.08 22:45:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
```

Per [SonarQube Troubleshooting documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Troubleshooting) , it's a good time to go check `web.log` and see what happens there.

Comment: Thanks! I had been misinterpreting the:  

    Process exited with exit value [es]: 143  

and taking that for the proximal cause of the halting, and been confused, since (as you say) the ES seccomp issue had only logged as a 'warn'.  

Examining the web.log is giving me a new lead to pursue (an issue with a plugin).

Comment: (also, to clarify, I had been meaning the 'temp/...' generated elasticsearch.yml above, rather than the static one under the elasticsearch package.)

Answer (score 0):

Killing all the JDK instance (pids)and restarting sonarqube services worked for me.